# SaxonJS performance conserns

Tags: node.js, saxon-js

I just found and started using `Saxon-JS` to be able to run Schematron validations on Peppol (Peppol.eu) messages and it works great!

I've "pre-compiled" the Schemat's needed into JSON (using `schxslt` and `xslt3`) and I am then executing the `SaxonJS.transform()` on the data.

As these stylesheets are fairly big it takes some time and performance is of key as it is run through a API.

I run the three calls in a `Promise.all()` and have added timers. From the timers I can see that the function calls happens in parallel but the execution of `SaxonJS.transform()` seems to be sequential, i.e. when the first `SaxonJS.transform()` returns the next starts...

I tried adding `threads` to the code to get it running in "workers" but I need to send a XMLDom object to the function and `threads`isn't supporting that it seems...

[image]

There's about `430ms` in between the two executions of the `runTransform()` and they are called like:

```
let [xsdResult, valid, valid2] = await Promise.all([
  xsdValidation(event, xmlDoc),
  runTransform('EN16931-UBL-validation-preprocessed.sef.json', event, ves),
  runTransform('PEPPOL-EN16931-UBL.sef.json', event, ves)
]);
```

Shouldn't the functions run in parallel (at least "more" in parallel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was another `await` in function `runTransform()` that was "blocking" and not the `SaxonJS.transform()` as initially thought...

Mind those Promises... :o